# Jquery smooth scroll - Only works properly when scroll bar is at the top when the link is clicked

Tags: smooth-scrolling

New to Javascript and have spent hours on this problem :/

I want to implement a smooth scrolling effect to move to different sections of a webpage. I am using this piece of javascript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if (this.hash !== '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        const hash = this.hash;

        $('html, body, .main')
            .animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800);
    }
});
```

This is the basic structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%">
  <main>
    <a href="#contactme"><div class="contactme-button">Contact me</div></a>
  
    <div class="section-1" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; background-color: grey; display: block;"> </div>
  
    <a href="#contactme"><div class="contactme-button-2">Contact me</div></a>
  
    <div class="section-1" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; background-color: blue; display: block;"> </div>
  
    <div class="contactme-section" id="contactme" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: grey;">CONTACT ME</div>
    <div class="section-1" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; background-color: black; display: block;"> </div>
  </main>
</body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        if (this.hash !== '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            const hash = this.hash;

            $('html, body, .main').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800);


        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

(there is more content in there but that is the basic structure that is giving me grief)

I discovered that in

```
.main{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

is stopping the normal operation of the scrolling and cause the second link to scroll to a random spot

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example on Codesandbox, Codepen, a Stack Overflow code snippet or similar environment that illustrates the problem and add that to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS declaration that may help here:

```
.your-anchor-element-class {
  scroll-margin-top: 36px; // <-- your value here
}
```

Browser support: Works natively in Chrome, FF, Edge, Opera. Supported in Safari with `scroll-snap-margin-top`.

[MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top)

Credit to [Josh Comeau](https://twitter.com/JoshWComeau/status/1332015868725891076?s=20) for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that in 

.main{
overflow-x: hidden;
}

is stopping the normal operation of the scrolling and cause the second link to scroll to a random spot. Any clue why?